# Editable elements, overwrite original text not working (x-editable)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been at this for a while and I can't seem to come up with a solution.

I'm using X-editable (Jquery) to allow users to edit an element in a page. It's mostly worked well, however I'm having a lot of trouble getting the address down. I edited the address.js file that came with the plugin so that there could be more fields (Street, City, State, etc), and they display correctly if you hit the "Edit" button.

However, when you submit your changes, it doesn't change the original text.

JSFiddle so you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/6puty174/

It's supposed to replace the original text when you submit your changes (you can see the example on the x-editable website: //vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html -- At the bottom "Moscow").

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think it's something to do with the changes I made in the address.js file. I've uploaded it so you can see what I've done: http://saulmarquez.com/test/address.js.  And the original one: //vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/inputs-ext/address/address.js.

I tried mimicking what I saw in the source code on the site's demo:

```
$('#acct-address').editable({
    value: {
        city: "Moscow", 
        street: "Lenina", 
        building: "12"
    },
    validate: function(value) {
        if(value.city == '') return 'city is required!'; 
    },
    display: function(value) {
        if(!value) {
            $(this).empty();
            return; 
        }
        var html = '<b>' + $('<div>').text(value.city).html() + '</b>, ' + $('<div>').text(value.street).html() + ' st., bld. ' + $('<div>').text(value.building).html();
        $(this).html(html); 
    }         
});
```

However, when I hit the Edit link to change it, only one text field opens (as opposed to the multiple that should) with the text [Output] [output]--and again, when you hit submit, it doesn't change anything. (I also changed the above values to correspond with the ones I added in address.js and the same thing happened).

Hope this makes sense. No idea what I'm doing. I'm still pretty new to javascript/jquery, and how all the plugins work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change HTML:

```
<div class="acct-sub">
    <strong>Address</strong><br>
    <span id="acct-address">5555 E. PEF Lane</span><br>
    <span id="acct-city">Phoenix</span>, <span id="acct-state">AZ</span> 
    <span id="acct-zip">85142</span> <span style="float: right;">
    <a href="#" id="address-edit">Edit</a></span>
</div>
```

Change JS:

```
$('#acct-address').editable({
    type: 'address',   
    pk: 1,    
    title: 'Edit Your Billing & Contact Address',
    display: function(value, sourceData) {
        if (value !== null) {
            $("#acct-address").text(value.street);
            $("#acct-city").text(value.city);
            $("#acct-state").text(value.state);
            $("#acct-zip").text(value.zipcode);
         }
    }
});
```